# Java EE Interceptor change return type

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I want my Java EE Interceptor to return a type other than what is defined in the JAX-RS service method, but I receive a `ClassCastException`. Here's a minimal example:

```java
    package com.example;

    @Augment
    @GET
    @Path("/me")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User me() {
        return new User(...);
    }

    @Augment
    @Interceptor
    public class AugmentInterceptor {
        @AroundInvoke
        public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
            runInNewResourceContext(resourceContext -> {
                Object original = ctx.proceed(); // is a User object
                return MoreData(original, resourceContext.getStats());
            }); // context resources are cleaned-up after the lambda runs
        }
    }
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.MoreData cannot be
>   cast to com.example.User  at
>   com.example.Service$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.me(Unknown
>   Source) ~[Service.class:?]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_201]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
>   ~[jersey-server.jar:?]    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
>   [jersey-server.jar:?]     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
>   [jersey-common.jar:?]     at

I'm guessing it's because of how my Java EE server was implemented: the interceptors are called from within a proxy for my service class, and proxies needs to return the type defined in the proxied class.

However from what I can tell from reading the JSR 318 Interceptors Specification, I don't think this is a design restriction. I don't see any info in the spec about return types/values, nor is the word 'proxy' mentioned.

JSR 318 Interceptors Specification:

https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=318

https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/interceptors-1_2A-mrel3-spec/

Btw I'm using Payara 5.192 (which uses Jersey 2.29) however I doubt it's relevant.

Questions:

1. Am I missing something in the specification? Or is there any other resource where this is documented?
2. Do any other Java EE servers implement Interceptors differently?

Answer (score 1):

General, JSR-318 interceptors, cannot change the return type of a method. Although I cannot find this explicitly in the specification, I am quite confident that this is due to Java language constraints. E.g. even if you convince the interceptor mechanism to return an incompatible object type, the caller of the intercepted method will get the `ClassCastException` anyway.

From the code you have shown it is obvious that you want to enrich the returned resource of a JAX-RS method. This is absolutely doable with another kind of "interceptor", the JAX-RS filters. Specifically for your case, the `ContainerResponseFilter` can intercept the call, after invoking the resource method. It can access the returned entity with `ContainerResponseContext.getEntity()` and replace it with the `MoreData` object with `ContainerResponseContext.setEntity(Object)`.

Example code:

```
@Provider
@Augment
public class AugmentFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        Object original = responseContext.getEntity();
        responseContext.setEntity(MoreData(original));
    }
}
```

Take a look at the specification to see how binding annotations work for JAX-RS, and you may need to iron out some detains, but the principle stands.

Comment: Thanks, but a JAX-RS response filter won't work for me; I should have specified that. The extremely simplified example code I gave does not convey the need for the interceptor to handle the call to the service method (ctx.proceed) itself.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I could change the return type of `me` to `Object` or `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` or maybe my own generic type `ReturnTypeHack<User>` (type erasure should enable the AugmentInterceptor to return a `ReturnTypeHack<MoreData>`), but I'd rather not in order to preserve the Java return type information in the service.